# Image processing using java and opencv

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing

I have to do a project of image processing using java and opencv libraries. I would know where can I find useful information because the most i've found is for using opencv with C  not with java. I also want to know what is the best image format to convert a bufferedimage into another one.

well, in my project I need to take snapshots and recognize some magnets from a whiteboard and then take the positions of them and save them in an array. The thing is that i've started with the project but it doesn't work because the image i've taken is a bufferedimage, and have to convert it to another format. I've read that bufferedimage is the best for acces to the pixel's information but it work so slow. I want to convert this format (bufferedimage) into another one, and the others posibles i've found are cvMat and IplImage. Are there other format good for working with? or if not, what is better cvMat or IplImage?

Comment: *"best image format"*  It depends on the content of the image.  Though of course, it depends on what you mean by 'best'.  I was presuming you meant 'smallest image size in bytes'.

Comment: You want to develop desktop application or android application

Comment: here is link to start java desktop application with open cv http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html

Comment: @FireFly  You ask that like there are only 2 possibilities.  I can think of 5, off the top of my head.

Comment: @AndrewThompson you might be true. OP wants open cv with JAVA. Open CV provides two library which is related to java. 1-OpenCV for Android, 2-OpenCV for native java. You can use these library in muliple kind of project

Comment: @FireFly  'native Java' != 'desktop app.'    Think 1) applet 2) servlet 3) command line based app.  --  Throw terms like that around & you can expect to have their meaning & use challenged.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Alright.

Comment: it is a java aplication. I've reformulate above what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can [start by setting up your environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13139808/176769) to build Java/OpenCV applications. The reference I just shared uses JavaCV, a 3rd party Java wrapper for OpenCV's API.

[Converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368078/java-bufferedimage-to-iplimage) [BufferedImage to IplImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906931/176769) or [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095653/176769) is easy.

Isolate objects can be done with [bounding boxes](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/). [OpenCV has a tutorial on this technique](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) using `Mat`.

If you need to access the pixels of `IplImage` you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721754/176769).